# Access Output from MySQL in another file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I want to access the variable "result" from the function which contains the query. 
When I want to access it from another file, in which I am trying to work with the output after a POST Request, the variable is declared as "undefined".

This is the file in which i execute the query:

```
const db = require('../db/connect'); 

module.exports = {

getID(name){
db.query(`SELECT CWID FROM user WHERE surname = '${name}'`, function(error, result, fields){
   if(error) console.log(error); 
   console.log(result);
       }); 
    }
}
```

And this is the file where I want to work with the data:

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res){
  const data = queries.getID(req.body.name); 
  console.log(data);
  res.render('new test', {title: "test"}); 
})
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of querying using mysql and async/await. This should do what you would like:

**Query file**

```
const db = require('./db/connect');

module.exports = {
    getID(name) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.query(`SELECT CWID FROM user WHERE surname = '${name}'`, function(error, result, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Main File**

```
router.post('/test', async function(req, res){
    const data = await queries.getID(req.body.name); 
    console.log("Query result: ", data);
    res.render('new test', {title: "test"}); 
});
```

The reason your result is undefined in your initial example is that you're using asynchronous i/o (normal in Node.js). By returning a Promise from getID, we can make async. calls easily and with some nice code syntax.